# Load images in Image Button

Tags: c#, wpf, image, silverlight

I am using below code to load image in my image button. But the Image is not loading in Button. However, I'm not receiving any kind of error.

XAML Code:

```
Image  Name="imgPhoto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="160" Margin="10,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164"/>

Button Content="Load" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="191,67,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
```

Below is the code to load the Image in Image Button.

Button Click Event Code:

```
  private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
               string selectedFileName = dlg.File.Name;
               imgPhoto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(selectedFileName, UriKind.Relative));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `UriKind.Relative`.
If you're building URI from file name, picked up from system's file dialog, then it is absolute URI:

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileDialog.FileName));
```

In other words, you should treat full path (e.g., "c:\folder\filename.ext") as absolute URI.

Answer (score 0):

with OpenFIleDialog we don't have **File.Name** we have only **FileName** property which Gets or sets a string containing the file name selected in the file dialog box.

check the below code

```
OpenFileDialog objOpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
objOpenFileDialog.Filter = "Image Files(.jpg)|*.jpg;*.gif;*.png";
 if (objOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                imgPhoto.Source =new BitmapImage(new Uri(objOpenFileDialog.FileName));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change imgPhoto.Source code as below

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string selectedFileName = dlg.FileName;
            //imgPhoto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(selectedFileName, UriKind.Relative));               
            imgPhoto.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(selectedFileName);

        }
    }
```